# Linq get distinct ordered elements without .GroupBy()

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

Given IQueryable<Product> with the following values in the database (values are fake, as well as names of an entity and fields):

```
Id     | CategoryName | Price
------ | -------------|-------
1      | car          | 10000
2      | boat         | 15000
3      | boat         | 20000
4      | car          | 5000
5      | boat         | 30000
6      | food         | 100
7      | car          | 15000
8      | food         | 200
```

I need to transform this IQueryable<Product> to IOrderedQueryable<Product> with values of the most expensive products in their categories, sorted in descending order by price. So it could look like:

```
Id     | CategoryName | Price
------ | -------------|-------
5      | boat         | 30000
7      | car          | 15000
8      | food         | 200
```

As IQueryable gives an ability to perform grouping and sorting in the underlying SQL query (and the real table contains about 10k rows with more complicated criterias on how to group to sort values), the key thing I want to have here is *performance*.

I already have a working solution which looks like:

```
IQueryable<Product> queryable = ...;
var result = queryable
    .GroupBy(
        x => x.CategoryName,
        (_, productsInGroup) => productsInGroup
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Price == productsInGroup.Max(p => p.Price))
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Price);
```

This solution results in a long query with GROUP BY and nested selects (to calculate MAX(p.Price), to choose the correct row in a group and so on)

Is there an ability to do it without GroupBy?
I'd like to have something like:

```
var result = queryable
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Price)
    .ExcludeRowsWithDuplicateCategoryName(); // Distinct by predicate
```

so that such query would first sort values in descending order:

```
Id     | CategoryName | Price
------ | -------------|-------
5      | boat         | 30000
3      | boat         | 20000
7      | car          | 15000
2      | boat         | 15000
1      | car          | 10000
4      | car          | 5000
8      | food         | 200
6      | food         | 100
```

and then just *somehow* exclude rows 3,2,1,4,6 as they have CategoryName already present in the rows above.

How do I do that?

Comment: What's your problem with GROUP BY?  How long does your query take?  Have you analyzed the query in SQL profiler and added suitable indexes? 10k rows is tiny.  Read them all into memory if you want.

Comment: Since this is linq to entities you prolly want a query that will translate to RANK/ROW_NUMBER partioned by Category ordered by Price

Comment: @Phil for now it takes 1.5-2 sec to perform a paginated query (skip some rows, take another rows). The value expressed as *Price* in the example is calculated by complex rule using several other tables and the CategoryName is really a column in a related table. Some indices present, but to be honest, I haven't used SQL profiler. It could improve performance, I suppose.

Comment: So what you saying is that the calculation of Price is probably killing your performance.  Fix that first.

Comment: @Phil well, I agree, that's correct point. But, maybe, there is still an option to avoid GroupBy in the example?

Comment: If you want to avoid the GROUP BY in SQL, get the 10k items into memory (e.g. queryable.ToList()) and then use GroupBy on that.  If getting the 10k items is slow you need to look at that first.

Answer (score 2):

The only alternative that comes to my mind is to use *self anti join* with comparison condition (or `NOT EXISTS` based query) like this:

```
var result = queryable
    .Where(x => !queryable.Any(y => y.CategoryName == x.CategoryName && y.Price > x.Price))
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Price)
    .ToList();
```

Whether it's more performant or not depends on the concrete queryable and the database table indexes.

It's worth mentioning that the above is not the exact equivalent because it will return more than one record per category if there are two or more elements with max price per group, so the exact equivalent would require additional criteria like:

```
y => y.CategoryName == x.CategoryName &&
    (y.Price > x.Price || (y.Price == x.Price && y.Id > x.Id))
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell the query in the post:
First finds the max price in a group

```
productsInGroup.Max(p => p.Price)
```

then finds the first element with the matching price.

```
FirstOrDefault(x => x.Price == productsInGroup.Max(p => p.Price))
```

Not sure if you can actually skip the group by but it might be simpler to take the first element from the group after ordering by price.

```
var result = Products.GroupBy(f => f.CategoryName).Select(gr => gr.OrderByDescending(p => p.Price).First() );
```